# GetAuthorizationToken permission error in AWS CodeBuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs, aws-codebuild

I'm trying to setup my Node project with AWS CodeBuild.

```
version: 0.2
phases:

  pre_build:
    commands:
      - $(aws ecr get-login)
      - TAG="$(echo $CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION | head -c 8)"

  build:
    commands:
      - docker build -t "${REPOSITORY}:${TAG}" .

  post_build:
    commands:
      - docker push "${REPOSITORY}:${TAG}"
```

When I trigger a build, command `$(aws ecr get-login)` fails:

> An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the
>   GetAuthorizationToken operation: User is not authorized to perform: ecr:GetAuthorizationToken on resource: *
>   [Container] 2018/10/26 10:04:12 Command did not exit successfully
>   $(aws ecr get-login) exit status 255

In IAM console, the user has these policies attached:

- AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryFullAccess
- AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryPowerUser

and both contain `ecr:GetAuthorizationToken` permission.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved. I needed to give `ecr:GetAuthorizationToken` permission to the role, instead of to the user.

Comment: Thank you for solving two horrible days looking for a solution.

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 3):

Had similar issue but attaching *AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly* or *AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryPowerUser* or *AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryFullAccess* policies to codebuild role did nothing

Solved by creating my own policy and attaching it to codebuild role:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                "ecr:PutImage",
                "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
                "ecr:UploadLayerPart",
                "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload"
            ],
            "Resource": "%YOUR_REPOSITORY_ARN"
        }
    ]
}
```